# How to normalize a wave function for different potential?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, normalization

I have 3 different wave functions for 3 different potentials. Basically, this is the intereaction for a diatomic molecule.
$$\psi_1(x) = 0, x<0$$
$$\psi_2(x) = C^{ibx} - C^{-ibx}, 0 \le x \le a$$
$$\psi_3(x)= 2A\sin(pa)e^{-kx}, x > a.$$

To normalize this function and find $A$
Is it correct to say that
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |\psi(x)|^2 dx = \int_{0}^a |\psi_2(x)|^2 dx + \int_{a}^{\infty} |\psi_3(x)|^2 dx= 1 $$ Furthermore, does it means that each integral gives the probability to find the one atom in a particular potential?

Comment: Is it a piecewise potential? Could you share the potential? What are $p$ and $b$? Is the first inequality supposed to be x<0?

Comment: You probably don’t mean $C^{ibx}$ and $C^{-ibx}$.

Comment: Yes it is correct to say those things and it is true that each integral gives the probability to find the atom in those particular regions (which are the regions of different potential) :)

Comment: actually to be clear this is a single potential that is piecewise continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have the correct idea.

The wavefunction should be continuous at the boundary of each region. So, a piecewise integration of $|\Psi|^2$ over the entire interval should enable you to find the constants. So given that $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} {|\Psi|^2 dx} = 1$$ you compute $$\int_{-\infty}^0 {|\Psi_1|^2 dx} + \int_{0}^{a} {|\Psi_2|^2 dx} + \int_{a}^{+\infty} {|\Psi_3|^2 dx} = 1$$ where of course the first term is zero.  So your expression above is correct and will enable you to find the normalization constants.

Evaluating the integrals for $|\Psi_n|^2$ in each region $n$ does indeed give the probability for finding the particle in the $n^{\text{th}}$ region.